# book (from 70's or earlier) where humans were aliens that killed off the indigenous life evolving on Earth?

Tags: story-identification

The theme of the story was humans were aliens that killed off the indigenous evolving life on Earth and took their place as the top of the food chain.  I believe this was discovered by the main character when he was in Africa and that it explained the gap between apes and humans of today.

Comment: It was all those telephone sanitizers

Comment: I know of a short story where someone finds this in cave paintings, but you're fairly certain this was a novel plot?

Comment: By "killed off the indigenous evolving life on Earth" do you really mean that they sterilized the Earth? Or did they just kill off some of the "higher" life forms?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104609/book-about-ancient-martian-astronauts-being-the-root-of-modern-humanity-and-time (which is newer [and described somewhat incorrectly in the question] but has an accepted answer)

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35044/novel-about-benevolent-aliens-landing-on-earth for a question about the series

Comment: That bare-bones summary of the revelation about the "backstory" of the modern human race also reminded me of Larry Niven's *Protector,* although I agree that *Inherit the Stars* is a likelier bet.

Answer (score 7):

This is a key plot element in James Hogan’s *Inherit the Stars*.  No spoilers for the rest of you.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that the OP was referring to this novel occurred to me as well.