# Book about ancient Martian astronauts being the root of modern humanity and time travel

Tags: story-identification

If I recall it correctly, this book has two main characters, both male, one of them big and well muscled. During the novel, they found evidence that the current human race descends from ancient Martian astronauts who traveled to Earth in prehistory, causing the extinction of prehistoric Earth humans, (which explains the Missing Link in human evolution).

Later in the novel the big guy travels back in time (no idea of how or why) to Prehistory.

And near the end of the book, the other main character, during an archaeological field research, finds remains of a human being who lived thousand of years ago, a human with large bones, and who holds an item that could not be made in that era (a gold plaque? A metal rod?)

That's all I can remember. I know it is not from the ABC, Asimov, Bradbury or Clarke.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you're thinking of "Inherit the Stars" by James Hogan?

Comment: Yes, Michael, it was!! 
Thank you very much!

I read it when I was a child so I was wrong about some details... Im afraid I mislead you a bit :-/ 

But anyway you managed to find the right title!!!
Thanks again!

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35044/novel-about-benevolent-aliens-landing-on-earth for a question about the series

Comment: Please note that we don't retrospectively "fix" other people's story-id questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To clarify the OP description of the book **Inherit the Stars** by James Hogan:  There are two main scientist characters who get called in when a 50000 year old human corpse in a spacesuit is found on the Moon.  This corpse, called Charlie, has a diary that they start to interpret. This gives them lots of info about Charlie's life and times.

Charlie has a buddy, Koriel, who goes with him in his wartime adventures on the moon.  He's the well-muscled fellow.  It turns out the Moon used to orbit a different planet, in the current Asteroid belt, not Mars.  That's where Charlie is from.  Koriel was leading a group of survivors of the war across the Moon when Charlie died.

At the very end a different research team finds Koriel's body, on Earth with dogtags, which they throw away since no 50000 year old human would have such a thing.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an edit to the question or are you answering it? If this is an answer you forgot to include the title and author.

Comment: Michael Stern gave me the title and author...
What Oldcat has written are clarifications about all mistakes I did in my question... Im very sorry for them, but I had not read the book in like 20 years! :-)
(Currently reading it again now) :-))

Comment: @Xantec - I thought a clearer description of the book would help future readers here decide if they want to read it themselves.  No reflection on Rasek intended.  We've all had that story we forgot or confused details on.  Kudos to Michael Stern for finding the answer.

Comment: Should I correct the original description or the perfect description that Oldcat provided is enough?

Comment: @Oldcat No problem. Just want to be sure to include all pertinent information in an answer. This ensures that if comments are ever deleted or links go dead that the answer remains viable on its own.

Comment: @Rasek Story-Identification questions are special in that our memories are rarely ever perfect, thus details in the question may be inaccurate or just plain incorrect and that is okay. This may make it difficult to find the correct story, but clearly not impossible. Just remember to accept an answer when it is correct, so that everyone knows it was answered.

Comment: Its been way to long since I read it. but I thought the Archaeologist found the casing  of a watchband/bracelet, Not dog tags.

Comment: Agree with @NJohnyy. It was Koriel's watch/communicator wrist band the archeologist found.  "Bah.  Russian or some such."