# Archaeologists find remains of survivor from planet that formed Asteroid Belt who was origin of homo sapiens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Story was about a planet that lay between Mars and Jupiter.  Some calamity happened, forming the asteroid belt. A (lone?) survivor reaches Earth when Neanderthals were the predominant Hominid form.  Probably mated with a Neanderthal resulting in modern homo-sapiens.    The conclusion of the story regards some modern archaeologists digging in an old river bed or such, , and the one doing the digging is distracted and misses the only remnant/evidence of the ancient alien's existence on Earth.

Comment: Do you remember what year you read it? Maybe a publishing date or a publisher?

Comment: This sounds like one of the Giants series by James P Hogan. Such a long time since I read them so couldn't say which one. Sorry

Comment: And this was a novel? A short story? A movie?

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104609/book-about-ancient-martian-astronauts-being-the-root-of-modern-humanity-and-time

Answer (score 12):

This is *[Inherit the Stars](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1712)* by James P. Hogan. As noted by user Danny3414 in a comment above, it's the first novel of Hogan's Giants series. The name of the destroyed planet was Minerva. At the start of the novel, members of a Moon mission discover a body in a spacesuit of unusual design.

The book has previously been asked about and answered here at [Book about ancient Martian astronauts being the root of modern humanity and time travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104609/book-about-ancient-martian-astronauts-being-the-root-of-modern-humanity-and-time)

Per the blurb on the back of one paperback edition:

> They called him Charlie. He had big eyes, abundant body hair and
> fairly long nostrils.
>
> His skeletal body was found clad in a bright red spacesuit, hidden in
> a rocky grave..
>
> They didn't know who he was, how he got there... or what had killed
> him.
>
> All the did know was that his corpse was 50,000 years old... and that
> meant that this man had somehow lived long before he could have
> existed.

Here's some text from the final scene you remember:

> It was about the size of a large cigarette pack, not including the
> wrist bracelet, and carried on its upper face four windows that could
> have been meant for miniature electronic displays. It suggested a
> chronometer or calculating aid, or maybe it was both and other things
> besides. The back and contents were missing, and all that was left was
> the metal casing, somewhat battered and dented, but still surprisingly
> unaffected very much by corrosion.
>
> "There's a funny inscription on the bracelet," Magendorf said, rubbing
> his nose dubiously, "I've never seen characters like it before."
>
> Zeiblemann sniffed and peered briefly at the lettering.
>
> "*Pah*! Russian or something." His face had taken on a pinker shade
> than even that imparted by the Sudan sun. "Wasting valuable time
> with---with dime-store trinkets!" He drew back his arm and hurled the
> wrist set high out over the stream. It flashed momentarily in the
> sunlight before plummeting down into the mud by the water's edge...

And the final paragraph:

> In the mud by the side of the stream below, the wrist unit rocked back
> and forth to the pulsing ripples that every few seconds rose to
> disturb the delicate equilibrium of the position into which it had
> fallen. After a while, a rib of sand beneath it was washed away and it
> tumbled over into a hollow, where it lodged among the swirling, muddy
> water. By nightfall, the lower half of the casing was already embedded
> in silt. By the following morning, the hollow had disappeared. Just
> one arm of the bracelet remained, standing up out of the sand below
> the rippling surface. The arm bore an inscription which, if
> translated, would have read: KORIEL.

This cover may be familiar:

[image]