# Alien race secretly oversees earth, ship named Ganymede

Tags: story-identification, novel

An alien race oversees Earth progress throughout history and falsely reports to their partners who really are their enemies. The enemies send a sub-lightspeed ship to meet Earth. Then they develop lightspeed communication. The ship gets lost and shows up later and assists to help defeat true bad guys.

I think the name of the ship is Ganymede but I could be wrong.

American novel. I read it in the late 70's. I believe the alien race is called Jevonese or jevlonese.

Comment: Can you recall anything else about this book? There might not be much to go on at the moment.

Comment: Where did you read (US, UK, elsewhere)? Do you remember anything about the cover? Was it a novel or short story? Remember any character names?

Comment: I believe you are referring to the book The Gentle Giants of Ganymede which can be found here:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35044/novel-about-benevolent-aliens-landing-on-earth/35046#35046

Comment: Actually, it's the sequel Giants' Star. The Jevlenese aren't even hinted at until that book.

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like **Giants' Star**, the 3rd book in the **Giants series by James P. Hogan**, possibly with a few elements from other books in the series (Gentle Giants of Ganymede, which *beichst* mentioned above, is #2 in the series).

The Jevlenese are 'alien humans' who live in the same solar system (but on a different planet from) a genuinely alien species (I think these are the partners/enemies you mention). They've watched over Earth for a long time and interfered in its history (IIRC, they suppressed human technology for thousands of years before deciding to push it forward instead a few centuries ago.)

That stuff is all in book 3. Book 2 introduces the lost ship you mention, but it plays a role in later books too. (Originally both species were native to the former 5th planet in our solar system, and that ship is from that era, preserved by extreme relativistic time dilation.)

The truly alien species are called 'Ganymeans' because humans first discovered them as remains in a wrecked spaceship on Ganymede; that's probably where the Ganymede reference comes from.

Comment: is correct. I should have been more precise in mentioning that while the Gentle Giants from Ganymede answer was in the same series, it was not the book in which the Jevlenese were introduced.  Good update and better answer.